# jqgrid disable headers

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a very simple question (I searched on google but found nothing).

How to disable header on a JQgrid, so that if the user clicks on a header: nothing happens (not sorting, not refreshing, and not appearing that little arrow on the right, but allowing to resize the column)??.

I hope you can help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

You only need to put:

```
sortable: false
```

On each column you don't want to be sorted and thats it.